# DIV background color smaller than div size when displayed as a circle via CSS

Tags: html, css, geometry

I have a div that is in the shape of a circle using the following CSS and displayed with the sample html.
With this, you have a pink box, with a black circle inside of it. 
What I want to do, is without making the inner div smaller in any way, make the black circle smaller.
So, in the end, the outer div is 100px high and wide, the inner div is 100px high and wide, but the black circle is only 70% of the size of the inner div and centered.

```
.circle
{
    border-radius:50%;
    background:#000;
}

<div style="background:pink;width:100px;height:100px" >
    <div class="circle"  style="width:100px;height:100px">

   </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ansancle/P8MY6/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try a radial gradient:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P8MY6/5/)

```
background:radial-gradient(#000 35px,transparent 35px);
```

Note that this won't work is some browsers, and in others you'll need vendor prefixes. Tested and working in Chrome and IE.

Comment: It looks smoother if you use `background:radial-gradient(#000 35px,transparent 36px);`

Answer (score -1):

Simply add the following property to .circle:

```
-webkit-transform:scale(0.7,0.7);
   -moz-transform:scale(0.7,0.7);
        transform:scale(0.7,0.7);
```

Comment: Inner div wouldn't be 100px though, now would it?